# Clip the stroke of an SVG

Tags: svg

I'm just tinkering with SVG for the first time, so I know little about the capabilities as yet.

I've created a simple donut chart - here is it:

```css
.chart-wrapper {
    max-width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-wrapper">

<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut-chart">
    <circle class='donut-ring' cx='21' cy='21' r='15.91549430918954' fill='#666ad1' stroke-width='4'></circle><circle class='donut-segment' cx='21' cy='21' r='15.91549430918954' fill='transparent' stroke='#303f9f' stroke-width='4' stroke-dasharray='75 25' stroke-dashoffset='25''></circle>
</svg>

</div>
```

As you will see, the outer ring overlaps the inner circle at present, but what I want is for it to sit completely outside the inner circle.

However, I'm unsure whether this is done via a stroke property, a clip property, or simply reducing the radius of the inner circle.

Whatever solution is available needs to be cross browser compatible and fairly robust for browsers circa IE11 onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer proved to be a simple one.

First I set the fill color to transparent.

Then I created a second smaller circle to sit in the centre which did not obscure the outer ring.

Comment: you should use none rather than transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately since the SVG spec does not allow specific placement of strokes, you have to simulate it with a mask. I expanded the first ring out a couple pixels and added a stroke (the stroke part of the mask is what is allowing the other circle to appear through. Works in IE 11.

```css
.chart-wrapper {
    max-width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-wrapper">

    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut-chart">
        <defs>
            <mask id="cut-off-ring">
                <circle class='donut-ring' fill="transparent" stroke='white' cx='21' cy='21' r='17.91549430918954' stroke-width='4'></circle>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <circle class='donut-segment' cx='21' cy='21' r='15.91549430918954' stroke='#303f9f' fill="transparent" stroke-width='4' stroke-dasharray='75 25' stroke-dashoffset='25'' mask="url(#cut-off-ring)"></circle>
    </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Opposite effect Jim - outer ring should sit entirely outside inner ring, not entirely within it.

Comment: Modified to use mask instead.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the circles in the opposite order so the inner circle is drawn on top of the outer circle.

Note that fill="none" is probably faster than fill="transparent"

```css
.chart-wrapper {
    max-width: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-wrapper">

<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut-chart">
    <circle class='donut-segment' cx='21' cy='21' r='15.91549430918954' fill='none' stroke='#303f9f' stroke-width='4' stroke-dasharray='75 25' stroke-dashoffset='25''></circle>
    <circle class='donut-ring' cx='21' cy='21' r='14.5' fill='#666ad1'></circle>
</svg>

</div>
```